# How do you write python code and execute it on a remote server?

Tags: python

I know there are many Python IDEs, im using PyCharm right now, files are on my local Mac, and when I run my code it runs on my local python interpreter.
How is the workflow if I would be writing a script for my Linux server, which is another machine?

I know I can write the code on the linux server itself, and execute it there,, but, is it possible to use still my Mac with my PyCharm and write code that reside on the linux server and gets executed there?

Comment: Store the code in a github repository, for example, and synchronize the repository on both machines. Anyway, this doesn't seem on-topic.

Comment: so, I wrote on my Mac, push to Github, go to the linux server, sync, and then run and test? There is no IDE that would let you write/run/debug remotely?. This process you describe sounds really cumbersome.

Comment: There is no IDE that will let you run code remotely as far as I know. In regards to "go to the linux server," it's trivial to write a github hook in python that will automatically pull changes from the github repo.

Comment: Also, tests shouldn't be run on a production server. The testing should occur before deployment. Workflow should be:
- create a PR on your repo
- travis runs tests
- merge PR if tests pass
- hook automatically pulls changes on master branch to your server

Comment: It is not a production server,, it is just a linux box, identical to the one in production,, but my IDE is on Mac, so I would assume the fact the code runs on my Mac doesnt mean it will run on the LInux machine,, specially if Im using python subprocess to interact with the OS,, since the OS commands on Mac and Linux are different.

Comment: well then you can have your server pull the pr and approve the changes rather than travis. Otherwise workflow is the same.